# Binary operations on graphs

Tags: graph-theory, abstract-algebra

Are there "binary operations" on graphs like in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_product), which make the set of all graphs ("under consideration")

- a (abelian) group or
- a (commutative) ring or
- a field or
- some other algebraic structure
  ?
  By a graph I mean everything which might be considered a graph, for example a directed graph, undirected graph, graphs with no multiple edges, weighted graphs etc. If so, is there a reference on how the binary operations are construced?
  I managed to find

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40590-015-0081-7

and

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571065314000092

but don't have access to it.

Comment: You should require the operations to be natural in some sense; better yet would be to specify an appropriate sense of "natural". Otherwise, the answer is that any nonempty set admits binary operations making it a commutative ring.

Comment: All graphs do not form a set, they form just a class.But the groups etc. usually are defined to be sets with operations.